# React Router LINK does not pass parameters

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, react-router

I have a React audiobook search application.  It grabs data from Librivox by author last name and displays a list of books.  Each item in the list has a link that in turn goes to a separate full book data component that displays 
all the data for that particular book (or whatever book the user selects from the list).

For the life of me, I cannot get the full data component to grab the book id from the URL (route):

Route defnition used by Link:

```
    <Route path="/book/:id" component={BookDataDisplay}/>
```

The BookListItem component (in SearchResults component) generates the following:

```
 <p><Link to={"/book/" + bookObject.id}>DISPLAY FULL BOOK DATA</Link></p>
```

Actual link generated:

```
  http://jstest.dd:8083/react_librivox_search/book/3277
```

But the BookDisplay component never gets this.props.params, which remains an empty object.  The render() method for the book display component engages, but there is no data with which to populate the book display, since the this.props.params.id variable never grabs the "3277" id number from the URL (without the book id, I cannot grab the data).

Any idea what might be going wrong.  I have been wondering whether I have to define PropTypes or ContextTypes to get the parameter passing to work, BUT I DO NOT SEE ANYWHERE IN THE DOCUMENTATION where it is stated that the passing works anyway but automatically once you have defined the Route and parameters.

I am using Redux, but I don't think that this issue has anything to do with redux, UNLESS redux commandeers ALL components and makes them ALL depend on updating the Redux store (I am not sending the whole book list down to the individual book data display component).

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a new account I can't comment. I had this same problem too. Are you sure you have spelled it correctly?

> since the this.props.params.id variable never grabs the "3277" id number from the URL

**Have you tried** `this.props.match.params.id` ?

---

This is my `<Link>` in another component

```
<Link to={`/profile/${this.state.comment.User.id}`}>@{this.state.comment.User.name}</Link>
```

And my Route

```
{/* ProfileView */}
<Route path="/profile/:user_id" component={ProfileView} />
```

and it works well...

[image: Shows the change working in the Chrome developer console]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try out

```
 <p><Link to={"/book/" + bookObject.id} params={{ bookObjectId: bookObject.id }}>DISPLAY FULL BOOK DATA</Link></p>
```

let me know how it went.

---

Hi, I read your message.

@Peter Hi, it seems like there is an error from other React code that you have. Can you please share the source code where it actually throws an error? Also, it is always a best practice to have "name='pageName' " in your Route tag. If you want to retrieve params from the other page, just use

```
const {bookObjectId} = this.params;
```

Comment: I tried that before, and I tried it again yesterday.  No luck.  I also tried using an onClick event with the link to send an action to Redux store to try to get the component to update via redux.  That was a disaster.  I got the error  the complaint that I couldn't "update state while updating state" (huh)?  Tried a variety of other things with redux and passing props that didn't work.

Comment: The problem is not grabbing the params.  It is that they are not even being sent along by the LINK component.  They remain EMPTY.  Both this.props.params and this.params are {}.  And it isn't that the component isn't rendering; it is.  Something or other is interfering with react-router LINK even SENDING properties.

Comment: Can you share full context of your code? Including full view of code where you have router, page component where you have LINK component, and new page component where you grab params?

Comment: I have changed things since posting the original.  Comments only allow about 250 characters . . . so I would have to create a whole new post here.  Stackoverflow doesn't seem to allow followup of the sort you want, although I would otherwise be happy to do it.

Comment: I have loaded it up to GITHUB.  Note that the Ajax call to librivox.org has been disabled and replaced by a two-item hardcoded booklist data object so that it can be worked on offline.  But you can also activate the live ajax link to librivox.org if you want.

AND . . .  the project is configured to be setup in a "react_librivox_search" subdirectory.

https://github.com/pkosenko/react-librivox-search

Answer (score 0):

I created a similar setup and it worked for me

```
URL - file:///Users/Arjun/react/static/index.html#/book/1

<Route path="/book/:id" component={BookComponent} />
```

Can you bundle your js (if you are using webpack or any other framework) and then run the application in incognito/private browsing mode just to ensure that the you have all the latest changes running on the browser. It is likely that browser history/cache is causing the problem.

Comment: I am actually already using webpack and creating a bundle.js.  I haven't been having trouble with any other changes.  They appear when I reload the app index page.  I am beginning to wonder whether it isn't my use of Redux.  EVERYTHING is wrapped in a Redux provider, including the individual book display page.  "App2" is the main class generated by wrapping everything (the original "App") in redux "connect".  See below.  So I am beginning to think that the BookDataDisplay component isn't working as expected because it has been commandeered by Redux.

Comment: Do you HAVE TO (as in MUST) use the "react-router-redux" module when you are using Redux as below?

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={librivoxStore}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="index.html" component={App2}>
        <IndexRoute component={Search}/>
        <Route path="/book/:id" component={BookDataDisplay}/>
      </Route>
    </Router >
  </Provider>, document.getElementById("appdiv"));

var App2 = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App);

Comment: Note that the whole app is being wrapped in a Redux provider.  And the main App2 wrapper class is being generated by a Redux connect function.

Comment: react-router-redux is required to sync url and store. This helps you to replay the same action again and again. I don't think react-router-redux is the issue here.
1 - Are you using hashHistory/browserhistory directly or are you using syncHistoryWithStore to create the history object? (I dont think this is the issue)
2 - can you change your route to <Provider store={librivoxStore}> <Router history={history}> <Route path="/" component={App2}> ... </Provider>
3 - Are you running your app on npm server?
If this doesn't work, please share your code. I'm not able to think of any other issue.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way you can pass more than one parameter. You can pass "to" as object instead of string.

```
<Route path="/category/:catId" component={Category} / >

const newTo = { pathname: "/article/595212758daa6810cbba4104", param1: "Par1" };

<Link to={newTo}> </Link>

this.props.match.params.id // this is 595212758daa6810cbba4104 
this.props.location.param1 // this is Par1
```