# Changing react route without NavLink

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have two pages. The first one is the homepage and has a search bar.
The second one is listing page which shows items which have been searched.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <ScrollToTop>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/tours/" component={Items}/>
    </ScrollToTop>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

in the Items.js, I have another component for search menu.

```
<SearchOverlayMenu/>
```

and in SearchOverlayMenu I have a simple form component called SearchOverlayMenuForm like this

```
<div className="text-right">
  <button onClick={this.handleFormSubmit}>
    <i className="fa fa-search"></i>
  </button>
  <input id="query" className="bfont text-right" name="q" type="search"/>
</div>
```

my problem is when I type a keyword in the query input and press the submit bottom, I can't use NavLink and I also don't have access to `this.history.push(...);`

and this is my 'handleformsubmit' function in SearchOverlayMenuForm component:

```
handleFormSubmit() {
    let query = document.getElementById('query').value;
    console.log(query);
    let newurl = '/tours/?q=' + query;
    this.history.push(newurl);
}
```

How I can redirect users to target URL?

Comment: you can use Link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically navigate using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Comment: @MonicaAcha how can I set input value into the 'to' field of Link?

Comment: this link solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670161/react-router-link-does-not-pass-parameters

Answer (score 1):

How about if you use [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate). It will make you redirect to the target page.